# Sum values if date falls within range (two dataframes)

Tags: r, dataframe, date, match, aggregate

I have two data frames that look like below:

```
id1 <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "4")
start <- c("2019-07-09", "2021-03-22", "2019-02-25", "2019-01-27", "2019-02-14")
end <- c("2019-07-10", "2021-03-27", "2019-02-27", "2019-01-28", "2019-02-16")

df1 <- data.frame(id1, start, end)
```

```
id2 <- c( "1","1", "2", "2" ,"2" ,"2" , "2", "2", "3","3", "3", "4", "4", "4" )
date <- c("2019-07-09","2019-07-10", "2021-03-22", "2021-03-23", "2021-03-24", "2021-03-25", "2021-03-26", "2021-03-27", "2019-02-25", "2019-02-26", "2019-02-27", "2019-01-27", "2019-02-14", "2019-02-15")
value <- c("0.5","0.5","0.5","0.5","0.5","0.5","0.5","0.5","0.5","0.5","0.5","0.5","0.5","0.5")

df2 <- data.frame(id2, date, value)
```

I am trying to match by id and sum the values in df2 if the dates fall with in the start and end date in df1.

The output should look like below. I've been trying to work this through dplyr and haven't had any luck.

```
###EXPECTED OUTPUT####

id1 <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "4")
start <- c("2019-07-09", "2021-03-22", "2019-02-25", "2019-01-27", "2019-02-14")
end <- c("2019-07-10", "2021-03-27", "2019-02-27", "2019-01-28", "2019-02-16")
output_value <- c("1", "3", "1.5", "0.5", "1")

output <- data.frame(id1, start, end, output_value)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to first combine the two dataframe using `left_join`, than make sure the `date`, `start`, and `end` columns are type of "Date", and make sure the column `value` is numeric. Then remove the `date` that are not within `start` and `end`. Finally `group_by` the relevant columns and `sum` up the value.

```
library(tidyverse)

left_join(df2, df1, by = c("id2" = "id1")) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(date, start, end), as.Date),
         value = as.numeric(value)) %>% 
  filter(date >= start & date <= end) %>% 
  group_by(id2, start, end) %>% 
  summarize(value = sum(value), .groups = "drop")


# A tibble: 5 x 4
  id2   start      end        value
  <chr> <date>     <date>     <dbl>
1 1     2019-07-09 2019-07-10   1  
2 2     2021-03-22 2021-03-27   3  
3 3     2019-02-25 2019-02-27   1.5
4 4     2019-01-27 2019-01-28   0.5
5 4     2019-02-14 2019-02-16   1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `lubridate` package's `%within%` operator and `interval` function is useful for this kind of thing. You could do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df1 %>% 
  inner_join(df2, by = c("id1" = "id2")) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(date, start, end), as.Date),
         value = as.numeric(value)) %>% 
  group_by(id1, start, end) %>% 
  summarise(output_value =  sum(
    ifelse(
      date %within% interval(start, end),
      value,
      0
    )
  ))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   id1, start [5]
  id1   start      end             output_value
  <chr> <date>     <date>                 <dbl>
1 1     2019-07-09 2019-07-10               1  
2 2     2021-03-22 2021-03-27               3  
3 3     2019-02-25 2019-02-27               1.5
4 4     2019-01-27 2019-01-28               0.5
5 4     2019-02-14 2019-02-16               1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to use the `data.table` package. Below is a quick way to get your desired output. You do need to make sure to convert your data.frames to data.tables.

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- data.table(id1 = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "4"), 
                  start = c("2019-07-09", "2021-03-22", "2019-02-25", "2019-01-27", "2019-02-14"), 
                  end = c("2019-07-10", "2021-03-27", "2019-02-27", "2019-01-28", "2019-02-16"))

df2 <- data.table(id2 = c( "1","1", "2", "2" ,"2" ,"2" , "2", "2", "3","3", "3", "4", "4", "4" ), 
                  date = c("2019-07-09","2019-07-10", "2021-03-22", "2021-03-23", "2021-03-24", "2021-03-25", 
                           "2021-03-26", "2021-03-27", "2019-02-25", "2019-02-26", "2019-02-27", "2019-01-27", "2019-02-14", "2019-02-15"), 
                  value = c("0.5","0.5","0.5","0.5","0.5","0.5","0.5","0.5","0.5","0.5","0.5","0.5","0.5","0.5"))

# convert value from chr to numeric
df2[,value := as.numeric(value)]

# merge tables by ids
new_dt = merge(df1, df2, by.x = "id1", by.y = "id2", all.y = TRUE)

# sum value when date is between start and end and group by id1,start,end
new_dt2 = new_dt[date %between% .(start, end),.(output_value = sum(value)), 
                 by = .(id1,start,end)]

# result
new_dt2
   id1      start        end output_value
1:   1 2019-07-09 2019-07-10          1.0
2:   2 2021-03-22 2021-03-27          3.0
3:   3 2019-02-25 2019-02-27          1.5
4:   4 2019-01-27 2019-01-28          0.5
5:   4 2019-02-14 2019-02-16          1.0
```